# ANTLR 3 RewriteEmptyStreamException on ID/NAME distinction

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

Given the Lexer

```
fragment
FRAGID : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
ID  : FRAGID;
NAME: FRAGID ('.' FRAGID)*;
```

Given the grammar

```
var_def: type=ID vname=ID ASSIGN expr       
   -> ^(VARDEF $type $vname expr) 
   ;
```

with options

```
options
{
  language=CSharp3; 
  output=AST;
}
```

and given the code

```
int i = 0
```

everything works fine.

However, when I want to allow the use of NAME in assignment (referring to another object)

```
var_def
  : type=(NAME|ID) vname=ID ASSIGN expr 
  -> ^(VARDEF $type $vname expr) 
  ;
```

I get at run-time *RewriteEmptyStreamException*

Antlr.Runtime.Tree.RewriteEmptyStreamException : token type

at Antlr.Runtime.Tree.RewriteRuleElementStream.NextCore() in c:\dev\stringtemplate_main\antlr\antlr3-main\runtime\CSharp3\Sources\Antlr3.Runtime\Tree\RewriteRuleElementStream.cs: line 200

at Antlr.Runtime.Tree.RewriteRuleTokenStream.NextNode() in c:\dev\stringtemplate_main\antlr\antlr3-main\runtime\CSharp3\Sources\Antlr3.Runtime\Tree\RewriteRuleTokenStream.cs: line 62

Doing some more investiagion, with the grammar

```
var_def
  : type=NAME vname=ID ASSIGN expr 
  -> ^(VARDEF $type $vname expr) 
  ;
```

I get a

Antlr.Runtime.Tree.RewriteEarlyExitException : Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.Tree.RewriteEarlyExitException' was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'i'` in:

```
int i = 0
```

will always become an `ID` token. Because both `ID` and `NAME` match a single `FRAGID`, and since `ID` is defined before `NAME`, there will never be a `NAME` token (in case of a single `FRAGID`). It will always become an `ID` token.

That is why this won't work:

```
var_def
  : type=NAME vname=ID ASSIGN expr 
  -> ^(VARDEF $type $vname expr) 
  ;
```

You must realize that the lexer does *not* create tokens depending on what token the parser is trying to match at a specific time. The lexer works independently from the parser.

Try avoiding the assignment of a label to a parenthesized group of tokens/rules. Instead of:

```
var_def
  : type=(NAME|ID) vname=ID ASSIGN expr -> ^(VARDEF $type $vname expr) 
  ;
```

do this:

```
var_def
 : type ID ASSIGN expr -> ^(VARDEF type ID expr) 
 ;

type
 : NAME
 | ID
 ;
```

Comment: Sounds interesting with avoiding  a label to a parenthesized group of tokens/rules. Can you please elaborate or give a URL so I better understand why this is a problem.

Comment: @CarloV.Dango, I have no reference for you. It's simply not possible to do `label=(A | B | C)`. Probably because inside the parenthesis, you could have multiple parser or lexer rules, making the assignment of a label meaningless. You *can* do this: `(type=NAME|type=ID) ... -> ^(VARDEF $type ...)`, but I find it rather messy.